# How to drag and draw a line on JPanel?

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to draw a line using MouseListeners and overriding the paintComponent method. I set up my paintComponent for now that draws a line on its own on the panel. But now I need to change it to when you click on the panel and drag your mouse to another point to create a line. I've been reading all these tutorials and I'm still pretty lost. Anyone who can guide me?

This is my code so far:

```
package gui;

import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DrawPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1697489704611349844L;

    /** The width of the panel. */
    private static final int WIDTH = 600;

    /** The height of the panel. */
    private static final int HEIGHT = 300;

    /** The stroke width in pixels. */
    private static final int STROKE_WIDTH = 1;

    /** The width for the rectangle. */
    private static final int RECTANGLE_WIDTH = 50;

    /** The height for the rectangle. */
    private static final int RECTANGLE_HEIGHT = 50;

    public DrawPanel() {
        super();
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));   
    }

class LineListener implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent theEvent) {
        theX = theEvent.getX();
        theY = theEvent.getY();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent theEvent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void paintComponent(final Graphics theGraphics) {
        super.paintComponent(theGraphics);
        final Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) theGraphics;

    // for better graphics display
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                         RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        final Shape line = new Line2D.Double(10, 10, 100, 100);
        g2d.setPaint(Color.ORANGE);
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(STROKE_WIDTH));
        g2d.draw(line);
    }


    public static void main(final String[] theArgs) {
        final DrawPanel panel = new DrawPanel();
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Drawing Panel Demo");

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're hard-coding your line parameters, 10, 10, 100, 100:

```
final Shape line = new Line2D.Double(10, 10, 100, 100);
```

making for a very inflexible construct -- there's no way your code can change this when the user clicks and drags. The solution is not to do this, to instead of using hard-coded "magic" numbers, to use int variables, ones that are changed in your code's MouseListener. Inside of the same MouseListener, you would call `repaint()` after changing the values of the parameters, and this will suggest to the JVM to repaint the GUI which will then re-call your `paintComponent` method.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DrawPanel2 extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 600;
    private static final int PREF_H = 300;
    private static final Color BG = Color.WHITE;

    // create fields that can be set in your mouse listeners
    // and used in the painting methods
    private Point p1 = null;
    private Point p2 = null;

    public DrawPanel2() {
        setBackground(BG);

        // create your mouse adapter and add as mouse and mouse motion listeners 
        MyMouse myMouse = new MyMouse();
        addMouseListener(myMouse);
        addMouseMotionListener(myMouse);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        // if your points have been set,.... draw them!
        if (p1 != null && p2 != null) {
            int x1 = p1.x;
            int y1 = p1.y;
            int x2 = p2.x;
            int y2 = p2.y;

            g2.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        }
    }

    // to set the size of the GUI
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    // my mouse adapter inner class
    private class MyMouse extends MouseAdapter {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            p1 = e.getPoint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            p2 = e.getPoint();
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            p2 = e.getPoint();
            repaint();
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        DrawPanel2 mainPanel = new DrawPanel2();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Draw Panel 2");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

---

Regarding your posted code:

- Have your inner class extend MouseAdapter. This class already implements MouseListener and MouseMotionListener as well as the wheel listener, and you only have to override methods that you want to change.
- Your latest code shouldn't compile since it tries to use two fields, theX and theY that have not been declared anywhere. I'm guessing that's just sloppy posting on your part, that you quickly threw this code into your question without bothering to try to compile it first. Please don't do this. We're volunteers trying to help on our free time, and your doing this just makes it harder to help.
- You should use either two Point fields (as I show above) or two sets of x and y int fields, say x1, y1, x2, y2, and set these in your mouse listener code.
- The mouseDragged and mouseReleased for your simple program will be the same and will only need to set a second Point (as per my example above), or second pair of x and y int fields, and then call repaint.
- The paintComponent method will then use both Point values (as per my example above) or both pairs of x and y int fields to draw the line.

Comment: Yeah I hardcoded the numbers on purpose just for me to learn how to see how drawing a line works first. My issue is figuring out how to implement the MouseListeners.

Comment: @Jasmine: then your question should be improved since you've not shown your attempt to solve the issue in the question itself. Please always post your attempt, otherwise we won't know how to help you. i.e., in the future, if your question is about mouse listeners, you should show us what you've tried to do with mouse listeners.

Comment: That's my problem, I don't really have any attempts since I don't understand how to approach this. The only thing I know is that I need to getX and getY for my points within a MouseListener method but that's it.

Comment: @Jasmine: doesn't matter -- you should still show what you've got. If you don't make an attempt you only cheat yourself. But I show you one way to do it in the code above using Points, but it would work the sam  with x and y int variables.

Comment: @Jasmine: more similar questions can be found in [this Google search link](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=java+swing+drawing+lines+mouse+site:http:%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F). Also if you've not done so, please check out the Java Swing mouselistener tutorial. Google those terms, first hit will likely bring it up.

Comment: I edited my post right now with my attempt. I don't know how to implement mouseDragged nor do I know which else needs to be implemented.

Comment: @Jasmine: see edit to answer please. Also please do take care to avoid careless errors in your code. Try to take as much care in creating and posting your code as you'd want us to take in crafting answers.

Comment: My apologies, I set my fields of x and y in my code but forgot to paste it into my post. Though it should be okay since the main focus is on the implementation of the MouseListeners methods.

Comment: @Jasmine: so you understand what you need to do now?

Comment: I was able to get it working, but with a somewhat simpler method. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

Look into mouse listener methods. You will want a mouse listener that stores a list of points which have been clicked or dragged. Then in `paintComponent()`, you can draw those points in much the same way you are currently drawing.

Lessons on mouse listeners: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html